# Question regarding extrapolating Peter Singer's 1972 paper--"Famine, Affluence and Morality."

Tags: ethics, utilitarianism

**"Famine, Affluence and Morality" by Peter Singer's conclusion**-- Donating to charity is morally obligatory and not supererogatory.

When further asked how much to donate-- as much as we ourselves end at the receiving end of the charity? He answers a somewhat 'Yes', saying morality in itself is very demanding.

**My question:**
Can we extrapolate this idea to-- earning as much money as possible, with the intention to donate, is a morally obligatory act, and not going out of your way to earn more is an evil act?

Using his "[drowning child analogy](http://www.philosophyexperiments.com/singer/Default.aspx)," if say saving that child means I will get a small cut on my arm, I'm still obliged to save the child. Right? If I am to get severally ill? Or say if I am to lose a finger? Lose an arm? Lose both the legs?

Is there any line that can be drawn before-- I will have to give my own life in order to save the child?

Some of you might agree that in most cases earning more money than you are now, is a possibility, but requires strenuous efforts, so much so as to affect one's physical and mental health, regardless of that, are we morally obliged?

Comment: There is no right or wrong answer, or absolute answer to that.

Comment: Thank you @Frank for your comment, but can we make a statement on my reasoning, is it flawed?

Comment: It think it's an informally logical extrapolation. I don't know if Singer has a mechanism to "draw a line" and prevent that kind of extreme extrapolation. You could make a case that what is "moral" is to kill yourself working more to be richer to maximize your philanthropic donations to others.

Comment: Hi @Saurabh. Recently, I did make a post on this same paper. I needed to discuss something on this. Could you please provide any contact of yours where I can message?